# How do I Handle Indices of BottomNavigationView in Android

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I have implemented a BottomNavigationView, where each item corresponds to a fragment. When a BottomNavigationView item is selected, the current fragment is replaced with the newly selected one, implementing a horizontal slide animation.

I'd like to keep track of the indices of the  BottomNavigationView items, so that I can check if the selected item is to the right or left of the current item and implement the correct transition animation.

I've seen many questions covering how to get the id of the selected item:

```
bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()
```

as well as how to set the item id:

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId()
```

but nothing on how to either initialize the BottomNavigationView's indices or access the id of a non-selected item.

I am new to Android development so I may very well be going about this all wrong, so if there's a more appropriate way to accomplish my goal - using different transition animations based on menu location - please let me know.

---

Update:
I've figured out that the items are already indexed, and can be accessed like this:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(index)
```

but I need to get the index of the item, not the item from the index.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out I can keep track of the current item index and selected item index, and after processing the selection, setting current = selected.

I'm doubtful this is the best procedure, though, and would appreciate some insight on how to properly handle it.